# Set classpath to include .jar file

Tags: java, classpath

I'm working with JGraphT API and trying to compile and run this demo (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/master/jgrapht-demo/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/demo/HelloJGraphT.java).

My current directory contains the .java file and the directory called jgrapht-0.9.1. jgrapht-0.9.1 contains the folder lib where all the .jar files are.

I've successfully compiled the file using:

```
javac -cp ./jgrapht-0.9.1/lib/*: HelloJGraphT.java
```

But I'm having difficulty running the program. I have tried:

```
java -cp ./jgrapht-0.9.1/lib/*: HelloJGraphT
java -cp "./jgrapht-0.9.1/lib/*:" HelloJGraphT
java -cp "./jgrapht-0.9.1/lib/*:." HelloJGraphT
```

Yet none of them worked. I am really confused about the syntax of classpath, and really appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add more detail about the error?. Some exception?

Comment: The error is: Could not find or load main class HelloJGraphT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must write the full name of the main class:

```
java -cp "jgrapht-0.9.1/lib/*:." org.jgrapht.demo.HelloJGraphT
```

Second, I am assuming that the compiled class is in directory structure in the current directory:

```
org/jgrapht/demo/HelloJGraphT.class
```

Third, you must use JDK6 or above in order to use wildcard in classpath.